# handsontable - close custom editor programmatically

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I want behavior which ESC button triggers by default, unfortunately that handler calls private methods so I cannot use it

```
case keyCodes.ESCAPE:
    if (_this.isEditorOpened()) {
      _this.closeEditorAndRestoreOriginalValue(ctrlDown);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    break;
```

any ideas how can I close the editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> destroyEditor(revertOriginal)
>   Destroys current editor, renders and selects current cell.

is what I need